# How to rotate a BufferedImage in Java?

Tags: java, image, rotation, bufferedimage, affinetransform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rotating BufferedImage instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918482/rotating-bufferedimage-instances)

The method I am currently using (below) results in a BufferedImage that becomes increasingly distorted with smaller angle arguments.

```
public static BufferedImage getRotatedImage(BufferedImage src, int angle) { 

    if (src == null) {

      System.out.println("getRotatedImage: input image is null");
      return null;

    }

    int transparency = src.getColorModel().getTransparency();
    BufferedImage dest =  gc.createCompatibleImage(
                              src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), transparency );
    Graphics2D g2d = dest.createGraphics();

    AffineTransform origAT = g2d.getTransform(); 

    AffineTransform rot = new AffineTransform(); 
    rot.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), src.getWidth()/2, src.getHeight()/2); 
    g2d.transform(rot); 

    g2d.drawImage(src, 0, 0, null);   

    g2d.setTransform(origAT);   
    g2d.dispose();

    return dest;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156518/rotate-an-image-in-java
The answer there isn't much?

Comment: You could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911610/affinetransform-rotate-how-do-i-xlate-rotate-and-scale-at-the-same-time/11911758#11911758) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964419/rotation-transform-not-working-properly-in-repaint-when-running-thread/13964860#13964860) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824684/change-the-angle-position-of-a-drawing-with-a-algorithm-in-java/12826882#12826882)

Comment: Are you clearing the image before drawing a new rotated version of it?

Answer (score 1):

> that becomes increasingly distorted with smaller angle arguments.

Sounds like you're doing:

```
 img = base_img;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   img = rotate(img, theta);
 }
```

When you really want to be doing:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  img = rotate(base_img, theta * n);
}
```

But I may be making assumptions that are untrue.